# Convert elements in List<string> to List<Texture> in C# (Unity3d)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How should I best go about converting the elements of

```
List<string> icons
```

to:

```
List<Texture> icons
```

I'm pulling filenames from an XML file (thus the initial string format) but I want to convert the filenames to texture format because they are dynamically formed at runtime so I can't load from the inspector.

Comment: What is the definition of `Texture` class? [This](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Texture.html)?

Comment: http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Texture.html - as far as I can tell - the only data from the texture class I'm drawing from is the name and/or path; since that's the only variable the Unity inspector calls for you to load and it's the only data naturally in the normal list<Texture>.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ConvertAll<T>`

```
icons.ConvertAll<Texture>(s => new Texture(..whatever conversion...))
```

or you can use LINQ to transform

```
from s in icons select new Texture(...)
```

both prety much boil down to the same. Difference is that  LINQ gives you an `IEnumerable` that pools data directly from string list (without creating a new list) so its good for once-off uses. If you need a persisten list of Textures either use `ConvertAll` or pin down the `IEnumerable` using `ToList()`